# ReactJs ContextApi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am not able to render my state present in Parent Component(App.js) in Child Component(Guest.js) in ReactJs.
I am not sure whether  at line number 11 {this.props.children} should exist or not.

**App.js**

```
1. import React, { Component } from 'react';

2. export const MyContext = React.createContext();

3. export default class App extends Component {
4.  state = {
5.   name: "Rahul",
6.    age: "29"
7.  }
8.  render() {
9.    return (
10.      <MyContext.Provider value={this.state.name}>
11.        {this.props.children}
12.      </MyContext.Provider>
13.    )
14.  }
15.}
```

**Guest.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MyContext } from "./App";
class Guest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Guest Component</h2>
        <MyContext.Consumer>
          {value => <h4>{value}</h4>}
        </MyContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Guest;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the state variable to be available in the `Guest` component `Guest` component needs to be children of the ContextProvider. Because the logic for the `App` can become complicated overtime, it is better to create a separate `Provider` component which will render the `Guest` component as children.

For example,

Provider component

```js
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

class NameProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "Rahul",
    age: "29"
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={this.state.name}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Guest component

```js
class Guest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Guest Component</h2>
        <MyContext.Consumer>{value => <h4>{value}</h4>}</MyContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App component

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NameProvider>
        <Guest />
      </NameProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Codesandbox demo [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kq515?file=/App.js:537-681)

Answer (score 1):

You have to render the Guest component in App.js in order for the child component to render.
Inline number 11 you are trying to render the children in of App component where you render this App.
 For example:

```
render(){
  return(
    <App>
      <div>hello</div>
    </App>
  )
}
```

Solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Guest from './Guest';
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
   name: "Rahul",
    age: "29"
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={this.state.name}>
        <Guest/>
      </MyContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: render is not a function

Comment: That is not complete code I just wrote a render method in a component. What I mean to say is the `div` in this render method is the child of App. When you render this.props.children in App component  text `hello` will be appear

Answer (score 0):

You can render to the DOM with `Guest` as a child of `App`.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App><Guest /></App>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

> I am not sure whether at line number 11 {this.props.children} should exist or not.

You may not(see other answers above).
The `Guest` component will be available to `App` component as `this.props.children`. see https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#propschildren

Answer (score 0):

THERE ARE TWO WAY OF SOLVING THIS 
1. TO CREATE A GLOBAL STATE MANAGEMENT
2. USE INSIDE THE CLASS AS A CONTEXT

I AM USING THE GLOBAL STATE MANAGEMENT
CHECK THIS OUT....!!!

**Context.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

const MyContext = React.createContext();

export default class Context extends Component {
    state = {
        name: "Krsnadil",
        value: 10,
        onClick: this.value + 1
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <MyContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </MyContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
export const Consumer = MyContext.Consumer;
```

**Guest.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Consumer } from "./Context";

class Guest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {value => value.name}
      </Consumer>
    );
  }
}
export default Guest;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Guest from "./Guest";
import Context from "./Context";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Context>
        <Guest />
      </Context>
    )
  }
}
```